# Spring Data JPA garbage collection

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa, garbage-collection

I have a `Spring Batch` application with `JpaPagingItemReader` (i modified it a bit) and 4 Jpa repositories to enrich `Model` which comes from JpaPagingItemReader.

My flow is:

1. Select `Model` (page size = **8192**), then i collect this `List<Model> to Map<String, List<Model>>` (group by id, because models not unique and i need to enrich by id) then enrich it with 4 custom `JpaRepositories` with native queries with IN clause, and merge them with `Java 8 Streams`.
2. Convert data to **XML** object and with Stax writing with `MultiFileItemWriter` to files, which are splitted no more than `20000` per file.

All works great, but today i tried to run flow with big amount of data from database. I generated 20 files (**2.2 GB**). But sometimes i got `OutOfMemory Java Heap` (I had 1Gb XMS, XSS), then i up it to 2 GB and all works good, but in Instana i see, that `Old gen Java memory` is always `900` in use after GC. It is about 1.3-1.7Gb in use. So i start to think, how can i optimize GC of Spring Data Jpa objects. I think they are much time in memory.
When i select Model with `JpaPagingItemReader` i detach every Model (with `entityManager.detach`), but when i enrich `Model` with custom `Spring Data Jpa` requests i am not detaching results. Maybe the problem in this and i should detach them?

I do not need to insert data to database, i need just to read it. Or do i need to make page size less and select about **4000** per request?

I need to process **370 000** records from database and enrich them.

Comment: You should chunk them into smaller bits instead of bringing all of them into memory.  Instead of reading 370K records into memory, you'll do better if you read 1K, enrich them (whatever that means), and loop through until all the necessary records are processed.

Comment: i use paging reader and read every 8k items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Added flags to my run configuration, and increase XMS and XMX twice.